# Error when execute some cmd commands with electron/angular

Tags: angular, typescript, electron, child-process

Example:
I run cmd command(nvm uninstall version node) from code angular/electron, after that, I run nvm list and I always see the version I deleted before with command uninstall. It is possibile to fix it? If yes how can I fix this?
Below my code

Function to open cmd and execute command

```ts
OpendCmd(command: string): Observable<{error: any, stdout: string, stderr: string}> {
    var _innerOpendCmdSubject: Subject<{error: any, stdout: string, stderr: string}> = new Subject<{error: any, stdout: string, stderr: string}>();
    this.electronService.childProcess.exec(command,(error, stdout, stderr) => {
        _innerOpendCmdSubject.next({error, stdout, stderr});
    });

    return _innerOpendCmdSubject;
}
```

Function to uninstall the node version using nvm (this.version = is my array with installed versions and works correctly but when I refresh page I see always version that I uninstalled before with this code)

```ts
async nvmUnInstallVersion(version:{version: string, isInstalledVersion: boolean; comboValue:string; }) {
    if (!version.isInstalledVersion) {
        this.version=this.version.filter(f=> f.version!=version.version);
    } else {
        let command = "nvm uninstall " + version.version
        await this.OpendCmd(command);
        console.log(command);
        this.version=this.version.filter(f=> f.version!=version.version);
    }
}
```